# Are there instances of a boon/curse given by one divinity getting reversed/mitigated by another divinity?

Tags: curse, boon

An example would be Indra mitigating Urvashi's curse to Arjuna to become a eunuch.

note:  this is not what this site calls "boon deadlock".  the reversal is done later after the boon/curse is first given unambiguously.

Comment: Many instances of mitigation, like Shiva making moon to undergo both waning and waxing instead of just waning like curse of Daksha.